# Short story about a young artisan an old woman and a living statue/mecha

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am trying to identify of a fantasy short story about a young German artisan an old woman and a living statue/mecha he must take care of. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You describe this as a fantasy, which normally means magic, but you use the term "mecha" which is associated with science fiction.  Is there something about the statue that makes this term more applicable than, say, "golem?"  When and where did you read this?